# Create variable with value based on other variables being NA or not

Tags: r

First of all, if this already has an answer on another post, I am sorry. I was not able to find it. I am sure this should not be that hard to do, but I am just not seeing it.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA), X2 = c(0.2, 
0.2, NA, NA, 0.2, 0.2, NA, NA), X3 = c(5.1, NA, 2.8, NA, 1.4, 
NA, 0.5, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a 4th column, `Variables`, which contains a string with column names that are not NA. See my desired output below.

```
   X1  X2  X3  Variables
1 0.3 0.2 5.1  X1,X2,X3
2 0.2 0.2  NA  X1,X2
3 0.3  NA 2.8  X1,X3
4 0.2  NA  NA  X1
5  NA 0.2 1.4  X2,X3
6  NA 0.2  NA  X2
7  NA  NA 0.5  X3
8  NA  NA  NA  None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`to loop over the rows, remove the `NA` elementgs with `na.omit`, get the `names` and `paste` it together (`toString`)

```
df1$Variables <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) toString(names(na.omit(x))))
is.na(df1$Variables) <- df1$Variable == ""
```

It may be better to have `NA` for rows that have all `NA`s

---

A similar implementation with `tidyverse` would be to use `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Variables = pmap(., ~ c(...) %>% 
                                   na.omit %>%
                                   names %>% 
                                   toString))
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Knew it shouldn't be that hard. Thanks a lot! Will accept your answer later, can't do it yet.